# Difference in QML between Window and Item in parent-children relationship

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm wondering why for `Item` this works:

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: (root or parent. It doesn't matter)
        onClicked: console.log("clicked")
    }
}
```

But for `Window` it doesn't. Only anchoring by parent will work, but for anchoring by id it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.fill-prop), `anchors.fill` requires the argument either to be or to identify an `Item`-derived object.

From [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) you can follow the inheritance chain of `Window` and see that it is not actually an `Item`.
Moreover, from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#data-prop) you can see that:

> If you assign an Item to the data list, **it becomes a child of the Window's contentItem**, so that it appears inside the window.

where for the `contentItem` we have that:

> This attached property holds the **invisible root item of the scene** or null if the item is not in a window.

Because of that, it makes sense what you are observing:

- the `id` of the `Window` does not identify an `Item` 
  → anchoring by `id` results in an *error*
- the `parent` is actually the hidden `Item`-derived `contentItem` to which each child of `Window` is automatically parented 
  → anchoring by `parent` correctly *works*